# Webpage Not Always Positioned Correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem on a website i'm making, if you look at my website:[NerdyFuture](http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com/). Everything will probably look normal, but sometimes when the page loads the text in the latest news box get's positioned very strangely. When i preview my website from my desktop(Notepadd++) the last news text appears as i should. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Picture how it looks like: [Picture](http://i48.photobucket.com/albums/f214/NerdZilla1/Schermafdruk2014-12-14144555_zpsaf161d9c.png)

Comment: Will your website give me a virus if I click on it? lol

Comment: hahaha, i can insure you that you won't get a virus.

Comment: This might take a while as you shouldn't be using positioning everywhere. Can update your post with the css and HTML to the boxes?

Comment: i'm sorry but I don't understand your answer, if you mean adding new articles with html then yeah.

Comment: I'm saying that your HTML and CSS needs a lot of restructuring. You shouldn't be using positioning. You should be using floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend setting text to `position: absolute`. Remove that from your headings and paragraphs and add `float: left` to your images, so they float next to the text. Now you will need to add a clearfix to  your `article` element, so the float gets cleared and reset for the next `article` element. You can read more about the clearfix hack [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).
I also don't recommend setting the headline to `display: inline`. Use `margin: 0`instead. Add `margin-right` for some extra space between the images and the text.

HTML

```
<div id="article1" class="Latest_Posts clearfix">
  <img src="lgg.png">
  <h3>...</h3>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Latest_Posts p {
  position: absolute; /*remove this*/
  margin-x: x; /*remove this*/
  ...
}

.Latest_Posts h3 {
  position: absolute; /*remove this*/
  margin-x: x; /*remove this*/
  margin: 0;
  ...
}

.Latest_Posts img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much!!, with some tweaking i fixed it now.